# Synchronize Liferay users with CAS-JDBC

Tags: jdbc, ldap, liferay, single-sign-on, cas

I have 1) SSO presented with CAS, which uses JDBC and database as identity store, 2) Liferay as client to CAS, and I need to synchronize users in Liferay with users known by CAS.

As far as I investigated, there **are** some [user importing mechanisms](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen15-integrating-liferay-users-into-your-enterprise-0) in Liferay. Such import may be initiated on user login or on Liferay's start up. But these importers are LDAP-based by default *(or may be I'm mistaken at this point?)* The problem is, I have no LDAP store, I can only use JDBC for CAS.

So, is it somehow possible to integrate my own import logic to Liferay from non-LDAP-based store? Which classes should I use or override?

Thanks in advance.